# Getting the locid from the maxmind geoip binary

Tags: php, geoip, maxmind

Maxmind's geoip csv files contain a locid, which I use as a key for my internal records.  It does not appear like the locid is available in the geoip city binary file when accessed through maxmind's php api.  Is that information available at all from the binary?

this is the class that is returned from the geoip_record_by_addr() function call:

```
class geoiprecord
{
  public $country_code;
  public $country_code3;
  public $country_name;
  public $region;
  public $city;
  public $postal_code;
  public $latitude;
  public $longitude;
  public $area_code;
  public $dma_code; # metro and dma code are the same. use metro_code
  public $metro_code;
  public $continent_code;
}
```

Comment: The location ID is not part of the binary.

Comment: Well, thats unfortunate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no locid in the binary. @oschwald is right.